# Problems in Login into Google using Firefox

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox3.5.3 using this i am unable to login in many websites if click on the login button itself an error message is coming . I dont what is the problem .if i try to login to google from ie or chrome its logging in . Does any one know what the problem is and the solution.

The error which i am getting is server not found that too only on clicking sign im

Comment: Have you some addons in firefox?

Comment: i dont have any addons

Answer (score 2):

I would uninstall and reinstall FireFox... does the issue persist? If so, may want to delete your FireFox profile completely and recreate it.
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_default_profile

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Tools -> Delete personal data anch checked all boxes?